# Acoustic plug-in not working at home but works at Guitar Center

Tags: acoustic-guitar

Just bought a A15V acoustic speaker and a Mitchell acoustic plug-in guitar at Guitar Center. It works fine when they plugged it at the store but doesn’t work at home. Any ideas on why and how to fix this? Could it be the amount of electric power? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, you must go back to the store and complain to them.

Comment: Did they use the exact same cords at the store that you used at home?

Answer (score 3):

Some basic troubleshooting may keep you from having to go to the store. First I assume the amp is an Acoustic brand A15V. Unless you have issues with the electricity at home the electric power is probably not the issue.

Does the amp power up when plugged in?

If you plug a cable into the amp and raise the volume on input 2 do you get a buzzing sound if you touch the end of the cable?

If yes to both the amp is probably fine. If no to either the amp may be the problem. If no to the second question it could also be your cable.

You did not mention the model of the guitar but it most likely uses a 9 volt battery for the preamp and the built in tuner. It won’t work without it.

On most guitars the battery is under the electronic controls. There is a sample pic of an inexpensive Mitchell guitar below. It may or not be the same as yours.

Sometimes a guitar comes without a battery. Sometimes it comes with a battery but it is wrapped in plastic so it doesn’t discharge. Check the battery compartment. Put one in if it is empty. If there is one there check that it is not wrapped in plastic and then place it with the poles in the right position. Of course also make sure the battery is good.

Sometimes a guitar will mute if the tuner is on so make sure the tuner is off when you test it. If none of this works then it’s time to go back to the store.

[image]

Comment: Some guitars with active electronics have a microswitch inside the jack which turns off the electronics to save battery life when no cable is plugged in. Cheap plugs with high manufacturing tolerances may not correctly activate the switch. Also, the cable may just be broken.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for your comment. I believe almost all guitars do, otherwise I will be buying some stock in Duracell or Energizer ;) I did mention the possibility of a bad cable in paragraph 4.